# Flow WMS not displaying in my map openlayers

Tags: javascript, openlayers, wms

I want to display a flow WMS in my map openLayers but nothing display. Here how i declare my WMS :

`var IGN = new ImageLayer({
  source: new ImageWMS({
    url: 'https://inspire.cadastre.gouv.fr/scpc/76758.wms?service=WMS&request=GetMap',
    params: {'LAYERS': 'AMORCES_CAD',
    'FORMAT': 'image/png'},
    ratio: 1,
    serverType: 'geoportail'
  }),
  visible : false,
  name : 'IGN'
});`

then when i declare my map in the layers :

`layers: [baseLayer,Terrain,foncier2,satellite,IGN]`

My URL WMS is wrong ? Or my statement is wrong ?

Thanks you in advance

PS : I work with OpenLayers 5

EDIT : I solve my problem, it was the wrong server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It it had been the correct server were some problems with your code.

The url is longer than necessary, geoportail isn't a server type recognised by OpenLayers and `visible : false` will stop the layer displaying.

```
var IGN = new ImageLayer({
  source: new ImageWMS({
//    url: 'https://inspire.cadastre.gouv.fr/scpc/76758.wms?service=WMS&request=GetMap',
    url: 'https://inspire.cadastre.gouv.fr/scpc/76758.wms',
    params: {'LAYERS': 'AMORCES_CAD',
    'FORMAT': 'image/png'},
    ratio: 1,
//    serverType: 'geoportail'
  }),
//  visible : false,
  name : 'IGN'
});
```

But even with those changes I get an error from the server

`Mauvaise Requête`  `Taille de l'image invalide.`

With a very small map it does work, but a tile layer works on any size map:

```
var IGN = new TileLayer({
  source: new TileWMS({
    url: 'https://inspire.cadastre.gouv.fr/scpc/76758.wms',
    params: {'LAYERS': 'AMORCES_CAD',
    'FORMAT': 'image/png'},
  }),
  name : 'IGN'
});
```

Comment: Thanks you very much I get it now , I wrote visible : false and wrote name : 'IGN' Because i display it when a checkbox is checked.